# Why use constant i in `tf.while_loop` as `loop_vars`?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The while_loop is like this:

```
i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 10)
b = lambda i: tf.add(i, 1)
r = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i])
```

`i` is used as a incremental variable. So, `i` is changeable.
Why we define `i` as a constant?
Why not `i = tf.Variable(0, tf.int32)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `i` is used as a incremental variable. So, `i` is changeable.

Not quite true — if it was, `i` could *not* be a constant.

`tf.add(i, 1)` does not change `i`, it takes tensor `i` and creates a new tensor by adding 1 to it. (In practice, tensorflow is likely to reuse the same memory allocation for the resulting tensor, but that is an optimization irrelevant to the logic of `tf.where`).

You may be confused because the same name `i` is used in lambdas, but all those tensors are different tensors corresponding to the output of operations at each iteration.

So, the `i` that you declare is actually the first value of your iteration (same goes for all the other values in the loop, not only for your counter). It is indeed a constant, 0, so it makes sense to declare it as such. It would be awkward to declare your initial value 0 as a `Variable`.

Answer (score 1):

tf.Variable can be used to create the same type of code.

The main properties of tf.Variable I understand is this. Reference is [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable)

tf.Variable has to be initialized before it is used by using tf.assign or executing an initializer or by loading its saved state from a file.

*Constant*

```
i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 11)
b = lambda i: tf.add(i, 1)
r = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i])
print (sess.run(r))
```

*Variable*

```
i = tf.Variable(0, tf.int32)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 11)
b = lambda i: tf.add(i, 1)
r = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i])
init = tf.variables_initializer([i])
sess.run(init)
print (sess.run(r))
```